# Saving data on GET request in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am building a simple mechanism where a user can like a post by clicking on a link. I'm using GET rather than POST as I want to allow the method to fire via the URL.

That been said how do I save data using GET? As the request data doesn't exist in this scenario... My model looks like:

```
class Like extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Like';

    public $belongsTo = array('User','Post');

}
```

and the method for adding looks like:

```
public function add( $id )
{
    $post = $this->Post->find('first', array( 
                'conditions' => array('Post.id'=>Tiny::reverseTiny($id)) 
            ));

    if (!$post)
    {
        throw new NotFoundException('404');
    }

    if($post['Post']['user_id'] == $this->Auth->user('id'))
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('You can\'t like your own post... That\'s just silly!');
    }

    if ($this->Like->create())
    {
            $liked = $this->Like->find('first', array( 
                'conditions' => array('Like.id'=>Tiny::reverseTiny($id), 'Like.user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id') ) 
            ));

            if(!$liked){
                $this->Like->saveField('user_id', $this->Auth->user('id'));
                $this->Like->saveField('post_id', $post['Post']['id']);

                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view','id'=>Tiny::toTiny($post['Post']['id']),'slug'=>$post['Post']['slug']));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('You already like this post!');
            }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Server broke!');
    }   
}
```

Can anyone help?

`<?php echo $this->Html->link('1', array('controller'=>'followers','action'=>'add','id'=>Tiny::toTiny($post['Post']['id'])),
                        array('title'=>'Follow','class'=>'follow')); ?>`

This part all works fine. It's saving a new row in the DB on GET that I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you just need to make a link to your controller action and pass you variable in the url.

to be clear the link on the post to like is in your post view : 
$this->Html->link('like this post', array('controller' => 'like', 'action' => 'add', $postId))

It should render a link like this :
www.yourWebSite/likes/add/1 to like the postId 1,

variables after your action (add) are interpreted as variable for your controller action

if your fonction add had been

```
public function add($postId, $wathever){

}
```

the url should look like www.yourWebSite/likes/add/1/blabla
where 1 is the first var for the add action and blabla the second one and so on.

this is the equivalent of a non rewriting url : ?postId=1&whatever=blabla

EDIT :

```
if(!$liked){
                //simulate the post behaviour
                $this->request->data['Like']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
                $this->request->data['Like']['post_id'] = $post['Post']['id'];

                //save the data
                if ($this->Like->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Thanks for your support !'));
                    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view','id'=>Tiny::toTiny($post['Post']['id']),'slug'=>$post['Post']['slug']));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Server broke!');
                }
```

}

Comment: Hi. Yeah I have done all that already (see OP). The issue is with saving the data on GET as normally you would save the request data, but that only exists on POST and no GET.

Comment: Ok sorry not sure I understand the question but for this : www.myWebSite.com/like/add?post=1&whatever=blabla you can get values from GET with $postId = $this->params['url']['post'];
$whatever = $this->params['url']['whatever']; Is that what you're asking about ?

Comment: No. The data is coming through fine. The problem is creating a DB record and saving it on the GET method as normally you would do this through a POST method. I tried the create and save but it doesn't like it.

Comment: Furthemore, Just a little optimization, the unique liking by user_post should be checked on the model and not in the controller that is to say using sql for instance : ALTER TABLE `likes`
 ADD UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_post_id` (`user_id`, `post_id`);

Comment: did you try to write $this->request->data['Like']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id'); and $this->request->data['Like']['post_id'] =  $post['Post']['id']; then the create method should work

Comment: Wanna add that to your answer. As that does work and I'll accept :)

Comment: @Cameron : Done, Happy for you !

Answer (score 1):

How about using `save with id=0` instead of `create`?

```
<?php

    $like = array(
        "Like" => array
        (
            "id" => 0,
            "user_id" => $this->Auth->user("id"),
            "post_id" => $post['Post']['id']
        )
    );
    $result = $this->Like->save($like);
    if(!$result){$this->Session->setFlash('Server broke!');}

    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view','id'=>Tiny::toTiny($post['Post']['id']),'slug'=>$post['Post']['slug']));


?>
```